# Array of arrays returning never[][]

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that takes a number and returns an array or empty arrays - with the number of empty arrays corresponding to the number argument.

See:

```js
function createMultiArray(columnCount: number){
  const columns = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < columnCount; i += 1){
    columns.push([]);
  }
  return columns;
}
```

When I try to feed the result of this function into another:

```
function getNextColumn(columns: [][]) {
  ...
```

I get this typescript error: `Argument of type 'never[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[][]'.`

Very confused about why this is. The Typescript docs say:

> The never type represents the type of values that never occur. For instance, never is the return type for a function expression or an arrow function expression that always throws an exception or one that never returns.

I don't see how how this relates to my function. There is something returned and I never explicitly declared the never type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript determines the type of a variable *at the point where it's initialized*. Whatever happens afterwards will not affect the type of the variable. Your `columns` array is declared like this:

```
const columns = [];
```

which TS infers to be `Array<never>` because no type information is given when the array is declared; it can't *look forward* to see that it'll be populated with arrays.

While you could indicate that the `columns` will be populated with arrays, in order for callers of `createMultiArray` to be able to do anything with it, you'll *also* need to indicate what sort of values can exist in an individual sub-array. So, you should make `createMultiArray` generic:

```
function createMultiArray<T>(columnCount: number){
  const columns: Array<Array<T>> = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < columnCount; i += 1){
    columns.push([]);
  }
  return columns;
}

const nums = createMultiArray<Number>(5);
nums[0].push(5);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Good tip about determining the type at the point where it's initialized.